# Change Dataframe to Vectors with Gouping by Vector Variable

Tags: r, variables

I would like to convert a data frame to a set of vectors.  The vectors would be each vector laid end to end with a grouping vector based on which vector the elements come from.

Example Data Set:

```
v1 <- c(5,5,5)
v2 <- c(8,8,8)
v3 <- c(10,10,10)

v <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

The result would be a dataframe with two variables:

```
w1 <- c(5,5,5,8,8,8,10,10,10)
w2 <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
```

Comment: You need `unlist(v, use.names = FALSE)` and second case `letters[1:3][col(v)]`

Comment: The Q does not show any research affort.